# How do I disable the "CD as package" source from the command line for ubuntu 12.04 LTS server?

Tags: 12.04, server, updates, package-management

I am trying to install or update software for Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS. I get this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease
```

and other such lines.
 Another user posted that this might be a problem if the CD is still referenced as a package. How do I remove the CD from the command line on a server?

Thank you.
Mike M

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the source list by editing the following file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

[This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine) may be able to help you more.